# Returning records(several columns) based on duplicate value in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please forgive the basic level of my SQL knowledge...I'm still self learning at this point.

I know if I run the following, I get t the full list of cards, names, and UID's.

```
SELECT  
Keycards.KeyNumber, Personnel.LastName, Personnel.FirstName, Personnel.SSN
FROM     
Keycards INNER JOIN
 Personnel ON Keycards.UserID = Personnel.UserID
ORDER BY   KeyNumber
```

I know if I run the following, I get the list of duplicate card numbers:

```
SELECT  Keycards.KeyNumber
FROM  Keycards
GROUP BY   KeyNumber
HAVING        COUNT(*) > 1
```

So how would I get JUST a list of duplicate card numbers, WITH names and UID's- based ONLY on duplicate card numbers...??

Comment: It will be helpfull,if you post sample data and expected output as well

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your second query into a subquery and use it to restrict the result set to contain only key numbers which occur in duplicate.

```
SELECT k1.KeyNumber,
       p.LastName,
       p.FirstName,
       p.SSN
FROM Keycards k1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT KeyNumber
    FROM Keycards     
    GROUP BY KeyNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) k2
    ON k1.KeyNumber = k2.KeyNumber
INNER JOIN Personnel p
    ON k1.UserID = p.UserID
ORDER BY k1.KeyNumber
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. Makes sense once I see it work. Thanks so much! I've got SO much to learn.